# Undertow application not starting up when running jar with dependencies

Tags: java, kotlin, undertow

I am practicing with Kotlin and wanting to run a lightweight Rest application. I have experience with Undertow with Jersey, Jackson and Weld CDI in Java.

I wrote the minimum to startup the web container and it's running fine in IntelliJ.
Altough, when I try to run the jar-with-dependencies with `java -jar app-with-dependencies.jar`, I get errors.

Main class:

```
package nl.orhun.samplerestapp

import io.undertow.Handlers
import io.undertow.Undertow
import io.undertow.servlet.Servlets
import io.undertow.servlet.Servlets.servlet
import nl.orhun.samplerestapp.config.JerseyConfig
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener

fun main() {
    val servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()

    servletBuilder.setClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
            .setContextPath("/app")
            .setDeploymentName("app.war")
            .addListener(Servlets.listener(Listener::class.java))
            .addServlets(
                    servlet("jerseyServlet", ServletContainer::class.java)
                            .setLoadOnStartup(1)
                            .addInitParam("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyConfig::class.java.name)
                            .addMapping("/rest/*")
            )

    val manager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder)
    manager.deploy()

    val path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/app"))
            .addPrefixPath("/app", manager.start())

    val server = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(8090, "localhost")
            .setHandler(path)
            .build()
    server.start()
}
```

Error:

```
$ java -jar target/nl.orhun.samplerestapi-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:48 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener contextInitialized
INFO: WELD-ENV-001007: Initialize Weld using ServletContextListener
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:48 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.4.8 (Final)
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:48 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoaderImpl because of underlying class loading error: Type org.osgi.framework.BundleListener not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerLogger because of underlying class loading error: Type org.jboss.logmanager.Level not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.weld.injection.spi.helpers.ForwardingJpaInjectionServices because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.persistence.EntityManager not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from io.undertow.servlet.osgi.Activator because of underlying class loading error: Type org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.weld.jsf.FacesUrlTransformer because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.faces.context.FacesContext not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry$OsgiServiceFinder because of underlying class loading error: Type org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
INFO: WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner$1 because of underlying class loading error: Type org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Mar 06, 2019 9:04:49 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.MissingDependenciesRegistry handleResourceLoadingException
<.... truncated...>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Malformed class name
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
        at nl.orhun.samplerestapp.MainKt.main(Main.kt:26)
        at nl.orhun.samplerestapp.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Malformed class name
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.checkForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:43)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:51)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer.addClasses(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:58)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createClasses(BeanDeployment.java:224)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:398)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:191)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:125)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
        at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.isMemberClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.getNesting(Reflections.java:138)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedConstructor.initParameters(BackedAnnotatedConstructor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedConstructor.initParameters(BackedAnnotatedConstructor.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedCallable.<init>(BackedAnnotatedCallable.java:34)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedConstructor.<init>(BackedAnnotatedConstructor.java:38)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedConstructor.of(BackedAnnotatedConstructor.java:32)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:168)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:161)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:58)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:157)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:161)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:161)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:80)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:77)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache$1.apply(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache$1.apply(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:51)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getCastValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:80)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:192)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:94)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:61)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:58)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -6
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        ... 35 more
```

Build segment of the pom:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>nl.orhun.samplerestapp.MainKt</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I am thinking that this has something to do with how I create the jar file but I'm not sure.

Why is my application not starting up when I run the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Undertow, but I use Weld SE in a servlet setup running on Jetty and ran into the same issue as you, it seems like. I had some luck with excluding kotlin-packages from the bean discovery scan in my `beans.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all"
       version="1.1">
    <scan>
        ...
        <exclude name="kotlin.**" />
        <exclude name="kotlinx.**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```

I tried debugging the issue, and for me, the `java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name` originated from the Java `Class.getSimpleBinaryName` called on some lambda in the body of `kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext.plus`, named `kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$plus$1` that apparently has the enclosing class `kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$DefaultImpls` which is 6 characters longer than the lambda class name, causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to substring the lambda name with the length of the enclosing class name to get the simple name of the lambda. This may be seen as a bug in the way Kotlin names/types lambdas. A least with respect to reflection.

I also tried replicating the problem by creating this interface:

```
interface Foo {

    fun fooBar(operation: (Foo) -> Foo): Foo

    fun plus(foo: Foo): Foo = fooBar { f -> f.plus(f) }
}
```

And it causes the same problem (with or without `operator` before `fun`). Making `Foo` a class, and implementing `fooBar`, makes the problem go away though. Don't know why.

Using for instance `let` in the body of `Foo.plus` didn't cause any problems. Probably because `let` is inlined. So if you can stay away from using un-inlined lambdas in interface function bodies, you might be okay. And you can always put the interface causing problems in a package of its own and exclude this from being scanned, if you are not going to inject it. Hopefully this problem is not widespread.

Hope this helped, despite not being an Undertow-specific answer!

**EDIT:** You can add the `@JvmDefault` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/index.html) annotation to an implemented function in an interface to create default method (Java 8 feature) compatible bytecode, and hence eliminate the problem described above. Note that you then have to specify the `-Xjvm-default=enable` or `-Xjvm-default=compatibility` compiler argument. More light is shed over `@JvmDefault` in this article: https://realjenius.com/2018/06/29/jvm-default/.